# Flushing something towards the bottom of a tabular cell, without affecting the calculations for the height of the tabular

Tags: tables

I'm trying to produce lines at the top and at the bottom of two cells of my `tabular`. The two cells both have some text in them, from which I want to take the larger cell to determine the width of both cells, hence the `tabular` solution.

The next step was to produce lines, for instance through the use of `\hrule`. For the larger cell the output is as intended: a line at the very top and at the very bottom of the `tabular` cell. For the smaller cell I intended to use `\hfil` or `\hfill` to flush the second `\hrule` towards the bottom, but `\hfil` seems to be discarded. What can I do to produce a line at the bottom of the first table cell, so that both lines align horizontally?

```
\documentclass{extarticle}

%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
    \textcolor{gray}{\hrule height .5pt depth .5pt}
    \bigskip
    \textsc{K E Y W O R D S}
    \hfil %\hfill
    \textcolor{gray}{\hrule height .5pt depth .5pt}
    &  \textcolor{gray}{\hrule height .5pt depth .5pt}
    \bigskip \textsc{A B S T R A C T}
    \lipsum[2]
    \textcolor{gray}{\hrule height .5pt depth .5pt}\\
\end{tabular}

%\begin{multicols}{3}
%
%\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Tabular only computes the widths, not the heights. Besides, for filling vertical space you need `\vfil`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create cells with equal height automatically with `tabular`. This is a case where `\valign` comes handy.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newcommand{\keyabs}[2]{%
  \noindent
  \valign{%
    \hrule height 1pt
    \vskip .5ex
    \hsize=\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep
    ##\vfil
    \vskip .5ex
    \hrule height 1pt
    \cr
    \noindent\textls{KEYWORDS} #1\cr
    \noalign{\hfill}
    \noindent\textls{ABSTRACT} #2\cr
  }\par
}

\begin{document}

\keyabs{something}{\lipsum[2]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\valign` is the “transpose” of `\halign` on which `tabular` is built upon. The `showframe` option is just to show the page margins (the thin rules).

If you want lightgray rules, change the code into

```
\newcommand{\keyabs}[2]{%
  \noindent
  \valign{%
    \hsize=\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep
    \hbox to\hsize{\color{lightgray}\leaders\hrule height 1pt\hfill}\nointerlineskip
    \vskip 0.5ex
    ##\vfil\nointerlineskip
    \vskip 0.5ex
    \hbox to\hsize{\color{lightgray}\leaders\hrule height 1pt\hfill}
    \cr
    \noindent\textls{KEYWORDS} #1\cr
    \noalign{\hfill}
    \noindent\textls{ABSTRACT} #2\cr
  }\par
}
```

[image]

Comment: Accepted the answer. One question remains though: could you explain how `#\vfil` works? How can a token follow a hash `#`...?!

Comment: @1010011010 It's the syntax of `\halign` and `\valign`; `##` stands here for the cell body (it's doubled because we're in a definition). I added a variant for colored rules.